# Do formal power series algorithms different from normal power series algorithms?

Tags: algorithms, power-series

As far as I understand formal power series is an infinite sequence unlike normal power series which try to approximate the function in a few terms.

So will *formalPowerSeries*$(\sin(x))$ differ from *normalSeries*$(\sin(x))$?

In general, will algorithms for finding formal power differ from that of finding normal series of some function?

For e.g:- there is this paper "Formal Power Series" by Dominik Gruntz and Wolfram Koepf. They give an algorithm to find formal power series of any function.

In my opinion, the algorithms will differ as in formal power series, convergence is not an issue. 
Please answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia puts it nicely: "formal power series are a generalization of polynomials as formal objects, where the number of terms is allowed to be infinite; this implies giving up the possibility to substitute arbitrary values for indeterminates. This perspective contrasts with that of power series, whose variables designate numerical values, and which series therefore only have a definite value if convergence can be established. Formal power series are often used merely to represent the whole collection of their coefficients."